# Jquery :contains selector without children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to do a function to change color (in this example) of dom element in javascript(jquery) but i have some trouble with :contains selector but i need to use because i don't have specific ID or class.

### HTML :

```
<p id="title">John</p><!-- contain John must be red -->

<div id="description">John</div><!-- contain John must be red -->


<div id="element">
    <p id="element1">John</p><!-- contain John must be red -->
    <p id="element2">Anonymous</p><!-- dont contain John dont change color -->
</div>
```

***ID in this code just to show you my problem.***

### Js :

```
$("div:contains('John'), p:contains('John')").css("color", "red");
```

### Problem :

This script make unwanted changes (#element2)

I already check : [Jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) but to simple dom in this example .

Testable example here : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/poignant_benjamin/se6wz33j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own filter that removes children elements and checks the textNodes of the current element only.

As the string you're trying to match is present in the comments as well, any use of `innerHTML` is out, so `textContent` is used.

```
$("#bug").on('click', function () {

    $("div, p").filter(function() {
        var clone = this.cloneNode(true);

        while (clone.firstElementChild) {
            clone.removeChild(clone.firstElementChild);
        }

        return clone.textContent.indexOf('John') != -1;
    }).css("color", "red");

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/se6wz33j/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use exclude the div with other elements,

```
$("div:contains('John'):not(:has(*)), p:contains('John')").css("color", "red");
```

---

If your html have chances of containing elements like this,

```
<div id="description">John<p>test</p></div>
```

Then ultimately you have to go along with @TrueBlueAussie's answer.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/se6wz33j/3/)

Comment: The rules changed... comment said it can occur anywhere in the text. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Oh Is it.? Then `:contains()` would be the preferred one.

Comment: It a light html version, it's supposed to work regardless of dom i need to change color on element only if text contain John but dont change color of parent element

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Can you give an example of what you talking about?

Comment: On my jsfiddle, when you click on "bug" button, #element2 become red because #element > #element1 contains 'John'